# Is the "Library of Babel" violating copyright?

Tags: copyright

The Library of Babel is a database of millions of random strings of text. Among this randomness, passages from other sources inevitably appear, such as the book of Genesis or works by Shakespeare, or [this question](https://libraryofbabel.info/bookmark.cgi?pfkgsxxab,46). You can also search the library for specific strings.

If a copyrighted work appears in the database, is it breaching copyright? If not, can I use that text without breaching copyright (provided I indicate my source is the Library of Babel)?

You can find the Library of Babel at [https://libraryofbabel.info/](https://libraryofbabel.info)

Comment: My question starts on the 18th line of the linked text, by the way.

Comment: Do any actual complete works appear? Ive looked at it before and despite it claiming that because of all the permutations of random letters one or more exact works will of course appear, I don't see any, at least not in their full form. I don't even see actual excerpts. Everything is garbled just words in meaningless strings. Looking at 18th line down I'm not seeing anything but random words and letters. What does it say?

Comment: The text is identical to my question. It goes: (random words)...The library of babel is a database...

Comment: Ok, I though it might be that....I have it on 22nd line...may depend on monitor size

Comment: SO, after I read your question i did a search for some of the most famous literary quotes I know...and I didn't get one hit that was actually in order. I did hit a string of words that if put together would equal the entirety of the text. Is this what you're talking about? I can answer pretty quickly if so. I just want to make sure we're comparing apples to apples

Comment: @gracey209 I think it's a dupe.

Comment: @gracey209 i found several hits for the entire last four lines of "Begin the Beguine."